# focus only works when I go to the button with tab, after that when I click on button focus is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code in which Jquery function is called

```
<script>
function FocusContent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Fire here');
    setTimeout(function () { $('.cSSFirst').focus() }, 0);

}
</script>
```

I have the link in the page as

```
<a href="#" class="skip" onclick="FocusContent(event);" title ="Skip to Main content">Skip To main content</a>
```

The problem is that when I press tab on this a link and when i click on the link it works fine. Now when i click on elsewhere in the page, and when I again click on this link, the focus does not set.

Can someone help please ?

Comment: I forgot to add this  <td>
                   <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org" class="cSSFirst">Three</a>
                </td>

Comment: it is working fine when you click on other content and come back. check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bvinod14/ws39dtmL/2/.
how you are considering focus is not working? 
if you provide working JSfiddle it will be helpful to understand exactly.

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue clicking one link to focusing on another: https://jsfiddle.net/epr9f36b/ seems to work fine.  Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the complete code

```
 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <a href="#" class="skip" onmousedown="FocusContent(event);" onclick="FocusContent(event);" title ="Skip to Main content">Skip To main content</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" title ="Google">Google</a><a href="http://www.microsoft.com" title ="Microsoft">Microsoft</a><a href="http://www.Deloitte.com" title ="Deloitte">Deloitte</a>
        <br />
         <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">
             <input type="text" value =" Some text " />
         </a>
        <table id ="table1" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                      <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org" class=""> One</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
              <tr id="Two">
                <td>
                    <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Two</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                   <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org" class="cSSFirst">Three</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                   <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Four</a>
                </td>
            </tr>              
        </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    function FocusContent(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('Fire here');
        if (event.which == 1) {
            $('.cSSFirst').focus();
        }

    }
    </script>
```

`onmousedown="FocusContent(event);` solved my issue.

Comment: This works great in Internet Explorer and even in Mozilla as well, but not working in chrome any idea ?